# Error: Could not find or load main class SnakeGame.Gameplay

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, class, oop

```
[screen shot of project and error message in eclipse ide][1]
```

i have already made and tested a snake game in java.A siple GUI development using swing.It was running pretty fine

But when i went to create a runnable jar file i found that the classes were included in the java default package.So what i did was make a new project and copy the used resources and class.But this is the error message that shows up.
As you'll can see main is already defined in the Game play class(reffer to the image) ,hence i coudlnt think of a reason why this error message would show.

I tried changing the workspace as well but in vain,and furthermore now on running the application(with warnings ofcourse) the used resourses woulnot load!
Totally in a mess!!

could the community kindly help me fix it?

if the image is not visible try this link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NF34x.jpg

Comment: Just curious, what's wrong with it being in the java default package?  That's where all my projects are.

Comment: How to you start the java application? Do you define the main class (java -cp... main.Class ? Or do you start the jar (java -jar ...)

Comment: @Nick Ziebert --well as for default package i tried making a jar file out of it but my used images and other resources wouldnt load.So right here I searched for the solution and someone suggested to create a package instead

Comment: @Thomas --Dint get you ,sorry for the in convinience

Comment: Guyz it would be very helpful if someone could figure out my problem ,going through a pretty tough time

Comment: I've been able to create runnable jars with many projects I created that were in the default package.  These jars had images and even sounds.  Renaming your package isn't going to fix your issue.

Comment: @Anonymous: If you could provide something to compile and test, then we can easily provide ways to create a jar file from command line. With images it is tough to say what is happening !!!!

Comment: In order to help you, you have to provide some more information. The error tells you that java can not find the main class SnakeGame.Gameplay... so the class Gameplay in the package SnakeGame. Is this class correct? Is there a SnakeGame directory in the jar with a Gameplay.class file in it? Has this class a public static void main-method? There are crucial information mssing.
What problems do eclipse show at the problems tab?

Comment: When you said "make a new project and copy the used resources", did you copy and paste the actual files into the new folder?  I'm assuming you did, and this is where the error lies.  Eclipse doesn't work like that.

Comment: okay gyz i fixed it @Nick was correct .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to include a package declaration? Remember, in order to run a java program that is inside of a package, you must include a package declaration.